# Migrating cloudbees application to amazon beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudbees

Cloudbees is shuting down its hosting services, so I am looking for migrate my java web app to Amazon ElasticBeanstalk.

**Question 1:** Is it the right choice?

**Question 2:** In cloudbees, all I did was chose the app cells (256m) and set auto scaling true. And never worried about anything else. Now while configuring the same in beanstalk, I see a new thing called instance type t1 , t2 , small etc in addition to software configuration tab where i set the initial jvm to 256m
So what should I select the instance type to?

**Question 3:** In cloudbees, the price was dependent on app-cell which means the jvm memory I chose, but it seems in beanstalk, i can set memory to even higher and price is charged on the basic of instance type. Is it?

**Question 4:** So saying, i just need to replicate the same setting i.e init jvm with 256m and set autoscale true, what should be my corresponsing setting in beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

This is an opinion and you will likely get differing answers.

#### Question 2

Instance types are all based off of EC2's [list of instance types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) and each instance's price is determined by memory and CPU. The [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) is then rated per hour. Do take a note of the Free Tier on that page though since you are new.

#### Question 3

Yes, it is based on the following (unless you are in the Free Tier):

[image: ec2 pricing]

For example, if you had two t2.micro's running, one for 40 hours and one for 10, that'd be:

[image: cost example]

#### Question 4

You'd want any instance you wish running as a Load Balanced environment with Auto Scaling turned on.